# How to add Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Crated laravel project using below command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

successfully created blog project "http://localhost/blog/public/"  after that added below code in "routes.php" file

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

but after that when i type "http://localhost/blog/public/about" its displaying 404 page.

if anyone have any idea please share with me

Comment: does `http://localhost/blog/public/` works ? Have you the `welcome` view in the views folder ? Also try putting this: `dd('route works');` in place of `return view('welcome');`if it works, you're missing the view

Comment: if you run "php artisan route:list" you see the about route in the list?

Comment: "http://localhost/blog/public/" working fine

Comment: screenshot the 404 page here

Comment: Check if the public folder contain .htaccess file.

Comment: "dd('route works');" this is working

Comment: so you have some problem with your view file: check in the view folder if you have it

Comment: sorry "dd('route works');" not working in about route

Comment: Does `http://localhost/blog/public/index.php/about` work?

Comment: @AmirBar  "php artisan route:list"  is not working it displaying command not found exception

Comment: "http://localhost/blog/public/index.php/about" working now i know the issue , thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I don't know how you serve the application, apache, nginx or php simple serving.

Lets start from here:

1. List item
2. open terminal
3. go to project folder (where the "artisan" file is located)
4. run: "php artisan serve"
5. open in the browser -> "http://localhost:8000"
6. you suppose to see laravel welcome page
7. now go to -> "http://localhost:8000/about"
8. now again you suppose to see laravel welcome page

Comment: "http://localhost:8000/about" this working fine , but "http://localhost/testProject/public/about" not working

Comment: http://localhost/blog/public/index.php/about working , now i know the issue thanks all

Comment: great, in general you are not suppose to type public in the url, the apache and nginx you point to the public folder. The browser use the normal routes you defined.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put .htaccess file to Your laravel home directory. It seems, You need .htaccess with next content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Surely, your apache mod_rewrite have to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing `about.blade.php` view for your `about` action.

Also check that are you getting control inside about route using below code snippet.

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    $testVar = "Demo data";
    return $testVar;
});
```